# Why my application is not compatible with my own devices?

Tags: android, google-play, manifest, compatibility, android-permissions

My application, I recently tried to put on the market and it is not compatible with the device that I developed on! I read similar questions and responses however they didn't really help me because when I try to remove permissions or add all screen sizes and densities. Here it is the manifest:

```
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!--  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Sensor" android:required="false"/> -->
```

```
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/rss"
   android:largeHeap="true"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
       android:name=".screen.SplashActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
       android:name=".screen.MainActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
   </activity>





   <activity
       android:name=".screen.ProgramLogActivity"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_program_log" >
   </activity>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is your device?

Comment: My device is Nexus 5 and on google play it says it is not compatible while  Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 are compatible.

Comment: A Nexus 5 doesn't have a large screen. FWIW, Google doesn't care who owns the device -- it goes exclusively by manifest and device features.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you All, I want to sum up things I learned by encountering with    this problem. The properties given in manifest files with the tags    like `supports-screens`, `uses-sdk` or `uses-feature` are actually filters of Google Play. You can find more details in this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html).

Basically, filters are given in the manifest file and they decide    which devices will be compatible or not compatible. In order to    support as much as devices possible, I suggest you to keep your    manifest filters simple; except then necessary permissions or    features, try not to add anything extra to the manifest file. If you need to use a feature, try using `required="false"`. Consider the fact there are some permissions requires `uses-feature` tag to be used and there are other permissions don't. Try to read about before publishing your app.

Here detailed information about [manifest tags](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

Try to support as many sdk's as possible. You can set it in the manifest like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Try to use `supports-screens` rather than using `compatible-screens` tag. It worked for me at least!

```
<supports-screens
   android:xlargeScreens="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:anyDensity="true"
   />
```

I hope they will be helpful for you too! Here the fixed version of my application manifest;

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<supports-screens
   android:xlargeScreens="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:anyDensity="true"
   />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"   />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Sensor" android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove  tag, and add just support screen tag as below,

```
<supports-screens 
  android:anyDensity="true"
  android:smallScreens="false"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove <compatible-screens >
```

or

Put below code and try

```
 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
```

Comment: I do have both of them(compatible-screens and support screens), do you think it is the problem?

Comment: Just use support screen tag, I am using it in my all apps, remove the <compatible-screens> tag. I have posted my answer with my support screens tag.

Comment: I remove  <compatible-screens > and it added 1600 more devices. Thank you